# selecting first span value from a group in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would want to select the first instance of an element in a page where many number of such elements are present with 'ID' which will not be same always.

for example, visit, http://www.sbobet.com/euro which lists lot of sports and odds, where I want to click on the first odds.

[image]

and the html structure would be like this,

[image]

I want to click on this first span value and proceed with some test case. 
Any help on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response.

I am finally able to click on the element, by this XPATH,

```
"//span[@class='OddsR']"
```

This clicks on the first occurrence of 'OddsR' values,  without giving any index.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two approaches two the problem:
1. If you are sure you will always need only the first instance:

```
driver.FindElementsByClassName("OddsR")[0];
```

If not, then you have collection of elemets and you can access an of those
2. Also, you can first identify any closest enclosing div and then you can use the same snippet as above:

```
driver.FindElementsByClassName("OddsR")[0];
```

This one is a better approach if page is a bit dynamic in nature

Answer (score 0):

Use @class attribute. If OddsR class you are intrested in is the 1st one on the page then just use Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("OddsR")). Webdriver will pick the 1st occurence (no matter if there are more)

Answer (score 0):

Have checked your link and I agree with alecxe, you should probably start with div. But i would suggest a simpler selector :

```
css = "div.MarketBd span.OddsR"
```

The above selector will always point to the first span of "OddsR" class within div of "MarketBd" class.